# What causes the RTSP streaming failure?

Tags: rtsp, rtsp-client

I am working on video streaming using RTSP protocol. Sometimes but not always, I observe streaming failure. When the client sends "DESCRIBE", the server responds with the following message.

```
>> from server [398] >>

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Base: rtsp://10.10.131.1:8554/video/TmMrb5Pigkhf8Ln/bmagic-3/
Server: GStreamer RTSP server
Date: Tue, 30 Apr 2013 20:52:12 GMT
Content-Length: 180

v=0
o=- 1188340656180883 1 IN IP4 10.10.131.1
s=Session streamed with GStreamer
i=rtsp-server
e=NONE
t=0 0
a=tool:GStreamer
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=now-
<<<<<
```

Normally, client will follow with "SETUP", but for a message like that the client seems to stop responding. I am new to RTSP, so to interpret this is hard for me. What could cause the server to send this message? What type of error does it imply such that the client chooses not to proceed?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to connection timeout. I would try to do this on your socket:

```
setTcpNoDelay(true);
setSoTimeout(60000);
```